# Unable to do SCP

Tags: scp, openssh

```
hqcomms@BWANFW01> scp export log traffic query "vsys eq vsys11" start-time equal 2014/04/24@00:00:01 end-time equal 2014/05/08@23:59:59 to FirewallLogs@apst:/inbox/traffic
Password Authentication
Password: 
exec request failed on channel 0
```

I am trying to export Firewall logs and it is giving me above error.
Both client and server are Linux/Unix based server.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SCP syntax goes: `scp [[user@]host1:]file1 ... [[user@]host2:]file2`. Your @ symbols will definitely confuse scp, but I'm not sure that's even what you're trying to do. Run your export first and then export the resulting file.

Comment: Hello Josh, I am bit new to do scp. can you please explain when you say Your @ symbols will definitely confuse scp what does that mean?

Comment: I want to export log file Traffic to another srver.

Comment: scp uses the @ as a token for recognizing user@host, so if you include them anywhere they'll need to be in quotes or escaped. Moot point, since you appear to be running scp to run a command, which you cannot do directly. Export your log first, then scp it.